# Error Code: 1424. Recursive stored functions and triggers are not allowed

Tags: java, mysql, database, function, triggers

```
Delimiter //
create function fn_calcular_subtotal(_cantidad int, _precio int) 
returns int
BEGIN
declare subtotal int;
set subtotal= (select sum(_Cantidad*_Precio) from producto join detalle_pedido on ID_Producto = Producto where ID_Producto = Producto);
return fn_calcular_subtotal();
END//
```

Comment: Please add the statement which invokes this function and explain what is supposed to happen. As is my guess would be that the calling statement invokes producto and detaile_pedido.

Comment: is the last line meant to be `return subtotal` rather than the attempting calling of the function again (without args)?

Comment: Looks like you'd use `RETURN subtotal;`

Comment: Your functions seems to be illogical. It will return the product of the parameters mutiplied on the amount of rows which matches joining criteria. And you do not need to apply the same condition twice - in ON and in WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to return **subtotal**.  At the moment you are invoking the function again in the return statement.

```sql
Delimiter //
create function fn_calcular_subtotal(_cantidad int, _precio int) 
returns int
BEGIN
declare subtotal int;
set subtotal= (select sum(_Cantidad*_Precio) from producto join detalle_pedido on ID_Producto = Producto where ID_Producto = Producto);
return subtotal;  /* <---------------------- */
END//
```